# error in search Angular 12 error :parameter implicity has an 'any' type'

Tags: angular, api, search

getting error in search function whenever call getting same error over and over. i am using api

**app.component**

```
`import { SelectorMatcher } from '@angular/compiler';
import { listLazyRoutes } from '@angular/compiler/src/aot/lazy_routes';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {ApiGetService} from './api-get.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  title = 'card-app';
  lis:any =[];
  li:any = []
  email: any;
  Res: any;
  

  constructor (private api: ApiGetService){
    
    }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getUserData().subscribe(res =>{
      this.lis=res;
    });


    }
    search(){
      this.lis = this.lis.data.filter(Res =>{
        return Res.email.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.email.toLocaleLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }
```

**api-get.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiGetService {
    
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
      getUserData(){
        let apiurl="https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";
        return this.http.get(apiurl);
      }
    }
```

**app.commponent.html**

```
 <title>Search Box</title>
        
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-11 mx-auto my-auto search-box">
          <div class="input-group form-container">
            <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Keyword" autofocus="autofocus" />
        
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success">
                <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/p1em/Very_Basic/search1600.png" width="40" />
              </button>
            </span>
        
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        
        
        <div class="container">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" *ngFor="let u of lis.data">
            <img src="{{u.avatar}}" class="card-img-top">
        
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="btn btn-primary">{{u.id}}</p>
              <h5 class="card-title">{{u.first_name}} {{u.last_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{u.email}}</p>
        
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


 *api = https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1*
```

Error:

```
 src/app/app.component.ts:31:39 - error TS7006: Parameter 'Res' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    
    31       this.lis = this.lis.data.filter(Res =>{
                                             ~~~
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't use words such as ASAP. Show us your tsconfig.json file

Comment: i use api https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1 which i have to fetch and sorry for ASAP.

Comment: You could have done more than just being sorry and removed them.